# Getting garbage value while calculating difference between already defined and current time (perl script)

Tags: perl

I have time (only in hours & minutes) defined in one text file and getting current time from machine. Below is my code and am getting garbage value as 3. Code in perl script. Data in text file is as:

```
                   ##ID::name::time
                   228::one::18 30 30
                   97::two::20 30 00
```

Code is as : Please suggest.

```
         my $timefromfile;
    open(my $fh, "<", $paramfile) or die("Can't open $paramfile\n") ;
        {
        print "before while\n";
    while (my $line = <$fh>) {
        print "$line\n";
        if($line !~ m/^\#/){
            chomp($line);
        #if line isn't blank, process it
            if($line ne ""){
                push(@all_linesSettings, $line);
                my @lineseparator = split(/\::/, $line);
                $timefromfile = $lineseparator[-1];
                my $namefromfile = $lineseparator[-2];
                my $IDfromfile = $lineseparator[-3]; 
                print "File Time for $IDfromfile $namefromfile is 
                    $timefromfile \n";

                print "**********\n";   
                (my $sec,my $min,my $hour) = localtime();
                printf("Current Time is in - HH:MM:SS format  ");
                #get time into a variable
                my @t;
                @t = ($hour, $min, $sec);           
                print "\n@t\n";
                print "\n**********\n";

                my $format = '%H %M %S';
                my $diff = @t - Time::Piece->strptime($timefromfile, $format );
                print "\n now slatime is $timefromfile\n";
                print  "difference in seconds $diff\n";
            }
        }
            }
        }
            close $fh;
            }
```

Comment: What do you mean by, _I am getting garbage value 3_ I do not see any result with 3, just 30, I also do not see the example file for where you store the time?

Comment: What's the error you're getting? What output actually is generated given your input?

Comment: @GerhardBarnard the data from example file is shown above. and the output for each is as expected but only for $diff am getting as 3

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 of troubleshooting perl: Turn on `use strict;` and `use warnings`:

- You try to parse `$SLAtime` but you don't ever define or declare it.
- You declare `$timefromfile` but with no `;` so that won't compile.
- Your indentation is broken. (You've mismatched brackets).
- You subtract a value from `@t`. That value is undefined because of the above and because you don't have `strict` or `warnings` just silently evaluates as zero. `@t` contains 3 elements, and that's how it's evaluated in a scalar context. That's probably where your `3` is coming from.
- You have a `printf` mixed in there, with no format string or variable. Which is a bit weird.
- It's unclear if you even load `Time::Piece` in the first place. Which makes it considerably harder to use.
- `Time::Piece->strptime` uses the epoch as your baseline. You're comparing with 1st Jan 1970, so your delta will be much bigger than you think.

Something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Piece;

while (<DATA>) {
   print;
   unless (m/^\s*\#/) {
      chomp;
      my ( $ID, $name, $timestr ) = split /::/;
      my $now = localtime;

#note - this assumes time stamps are from today, which may not be what you want.
      my $converted_time = Time::Piece->strptime(
         join( " ", $timestr, $now->year, $now->mon, $now->mday ),
         '%H %M %S %Y %m %d' );

      my $diff = $converted_time - $now;

      print "Diff is: $diff s\n";


   }
}


__DATA__
##ID::name::time
228::one::18 30 30
97::two::20 30 00
```

Gets you a bit closer.

Comment: edited code, $timefromfile is the only variable. strict, warnings and Time:peice is all loaded in my code. Here only the relevant part of code is presented.

Comment: It's useful to indicate when it's a snippet. It's even more useful to supply a runnable example, so we don't have to rewrite it to get to that point first.

Comment: I'll make sure to include those things in my write up, however I need the difference between time in DATA and current time.

Answer (score 1):

```
my $diff = @t - Time::Piece->strptime($SLAtime, $format );
```

I'm guessing that you expect this to do a pairwise subtraction?  (i.e., Subtract the first item in each list, then the second item, then the third item.)

It doesn't.

It evaluates each of the operands in scalar context, then subtracts those scalars.  If one of the scalars is a string, it will first be coerced into a number.

When an array is evaluated in scalar context, the result is the number of items in the array.

So:

- You start with `@t - Time::Piece->strptime($SLAtime, $format )`
- `@t` is an array with three items in it and the `strptime` is a string looking something like "Sunday 3rd Nov, 1943" (the example from the `Time::Piece` docs; I don't know what your `$format` looks like), so the subtraction becomes `3 - "Sunday 3rd Nov, 1943"`
- "Sunday 3rd Nov, 1943" doesn't start with a digit, so its value as a number is `0`, making your subtraction `3 - 0`
- Therefore, you always get `3` as the result.

If you want to subtract dates and/or times correctly, take a look at the [DateTime](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime) module, which includes methods for performing date arithmetic.

Comment: I'm guessing that you expect this to do a pairwise subtraction? (i.e., Subtract the first item in each list, then the second item, then the third item.)::::::::::: yes exactly. How can I achieve that. I am new to perl and not able to make it from DateTime as well. Please suggest

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to subtract a `Time::Piece` object from an array, which won't work.

You need to get the current time into a `Time::Piece` object too, and then subtracting them will return a `Time::Seconds` object, like this:

```
use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds;
my $current_time = Time::Piece->localtime();
my $timefromfile="2018-01-17 18 30 30";
my $format = "%Y-%m-%d %H %M %S";
my $diff = $current_time - Time::Piece->strptime($timefromfile, $format);
print "Difference in seconds is ", $diff->seconds(), "\n";
```

You'll also need to give the date to the `strptime` command. If you know the date is always today (and watch out for this around midnight) then you can simply do this:

```
my $timefromfile = $current_time->ymd() . " 18 30 30";
```

*NOTE!* I'm putting in the time from file as a hard-coded constant so the code above is runnable. You'll need to adapt accordingly.